# Replicating Stata sureg and Wald test results in R

Tags: r, testing, stata

I am trying to replicate the results of a Stata code snippet that performs a `sureg` regression and calculates p-values of a Wald test. Here's the Stata code I'm trying to replicate in R:

```
sureg (y_1 a b c d ) (y_2 a b c d ) (y_3 a b c d ) ((y_4 a b c d )
nlcom (ratio1: [y_1 ]a/[y_1]b) (ratio2: [y_2 ]a/[y_2 ]b) (ratio3: [y_3]a/[y_3]b)  (ratio4: [y_4]a/[y_4]b), post
test _test _b[ratio1] = _b[ratio2] = _b[ratio3] = _b[ratio4]
```

I have successfully replicated the `sureg` and the `nlcom` parts of the code in R.
However, I am struggling with replicating the test result. It seems to me that I need to perform a Wald test on the equality of the coefficients of the ratio `a/b` in the 4 regressions, but I cannot find a way of doing it that gives me the same results as in Stata.

How would you proceed?